# Read JSON data from javascript and trim string

Tags: javascript, json

I have json file like this,

```
{
    "data":{
        "type": "runjob",
        "id": "1",
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "input",
                "value": "d:\\My\\filestore\\JMJ\\Content\\input.xml"
            },
            {
                "name": "cmd",
                "value": "test.js //NoLogo"
            },
            {
                "name": "output",
                "value": "d:\\My\\filestore\\JMJ\\Content\\output.xml"
            }
        ],
        "disabled": false
    }
}
```

I need to read the velues, input.xml and output.xml using javascript.. How can I get those value?

```
 var stdin = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll();
 var json = eval('(' + stdin + ')');

 var log = new Log(json.data.inputs[?]);
```

Comment: `jason` ==> `json`.

Comment: Do not use `eval` to parse JSON. Use `JSON.parse`. As for how to access variables within the resulting JS object, this is rudimentary: use `array[n]` to access the *n*th element of an array, or `object.prop` to access a property on an object. To "trim" a string (I guess you mean find some trailing part), there are several alternatives, including using a regexp such as `/[^\\]*$/`.

Answer (score 0):

`json.data.inputs` is an array (note it's `json`; as Tushar pointed out, you <s>have</s> *had* `jason` in the question). So you can use any technique for accessing or looping through an array that's supported by your environment. It look slike you're using JScript on Windows Script Host; last I checked it didn't even have ES5 features, so perhaps a simple `for` loop:

```
var i;
var inputs = json.data.inputs;
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i ){
    // Here, inputs[i].name will be the name ("input", "cmd", "output")
    // and inputs[i].value will be the value ("d:\\My\\filestore\\JMJ\\Content\\input.xml", for instance)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

json.data.inputs is an array containing 3 json objects; you want the value property of the first and the third elements:

```
 json.data.inputs[0].value; // "d:\\My\\filestore\\JMJ\\Content\\input.xml"
 json.data.inputs[2].value; // "d:\\My\\filestore\\JMJ\\Content\\output.xml"
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, please provide any explanation you can to make sure people understand what is happening here.